# When aggregating on an empty dataframe, Pandas agg function converts result column type to float64. How can I make sure the type stays consistent?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas
from decimal import Decimal


base_data = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'name':'Sarah', 'balance': Decimal(1)}, index = [0])

## drop the first row and aggregate
summary_data = base_data.drop(0).groupby('name').agg({'balance' : 'sum'})

summary_data.balance.dtype
```

yields

```
dtype('float64')
```

instead of `Decimal` or `dtype('O')` as it should.

This problem causes a type error later in my code, when I do a left join, fill with zeros, and try to add another decimal to the float64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recast your dataframe with `astype`

```
summary_data = base_data.drop(0).groupby('name').agg({'balance' : 'sum'}).astype(base_data.dtypes)
```